# python program to get n unique sequence number within a range

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy-ndarray

the input is the range and total number needed.

consider input range is (0,1)

if the total number needed is 10.Then output should be an array containing 10 values between 0 to 1. including 0 and 1.

if the total number needed is 5.Then output should be an array containing 5 values between 0 to 1. including 0 and 1.

Comment: How about `np.linspace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Arithmetic Progression problem.
Using the formula
Tn = a + (i-1) * d
b = a + (n-1) * d

```py
# input range
a = 0
b = 1
# total number needed
n = 5

d = (b-a)/(n-1)
arr = [a+(i-1)*d for i in range(1, n+1)]

print(arr)
```